# Safari AutoFill/Preferences

Tags: icloud, safari, keychain, preferences

My question is: where does one find this option in the preferences for Safari Version 7.0.3 (9537.75.14)? I cannot find this option anywhere: not in Mac OS X System Preferences or in Safari’s own Preferences. I would love to be able to save the passwords for these sites, so that I don’t have to keep regenerating and re-remembering them.

[image: Allow AutoFill even for websites that request passwords not be saved]

Answer (score 2):

It's gone. Use this extension to work around it:
http://ozymandias.me/2013/05/08/force-autocomplete-on-in-safari/

Comment: Link has gone so the reason for closing link answers is correct again

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing it has been removed from Safari. According to [this knowledge base article](http://support.apple.com/kb/TS4644) (under "Safari isn't automatically filling in account names and passwords on some web sites.") The checkbox should be in `Preferences > Passwords`. I don't see it there on my computer which has the exact same Safari Version with no Private Browsing.